# What is the best way to convert .vob files copied directly from a DVD into a format usable by Premiere Pro?

Tags: file-formats, dvd

I need to import some video material that was copied directly from a DVD into Premiere Pro. (Disclaimer: This is for educational purposes, in that context it is lawful to use excerpts of commercial films in Germany).

They were directly copied, meaning I don't have an image of the DVD, but the original file structure from the DVD including the folders `VIDEO_TS` and `AUDIO_TS`, containing `.VOB` files. Premiere Pro can't import them.

What is the best way to convert/copy those files to get them into a format that Premiere Pro can use? By 'best' I mean with the least quality loss possible and in a way that will produce either one file that has the entire movie in them or an array of sorted files that will be easy to look through. No I don't have the original DVD. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ffmpeg, cat and remux all the VOBs together to a MPEG program stream.

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:vts01_1.vob|vts01_2.vob|vts01_3.vob" -c copy -f dvd dvd.mpg
```

(You may have to escape the `|` character i.e. `vts01_1.vob\|vts01_2.vob\|vts01_3.vob`)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for the video. However there's no sound in either VLC player or Premiere Pro (after import). Any idea how I get the sound too?
This was the query:
ffmpeg -i "concat:VTS_01_1.VOB|VTS_01_1.VOB|VTS_01_2.VOB|VTS_01_3.VOB|VTS_01_4.VOB|VTS_01_5.VOB|VTS_01_6.VOB" -c copy AZZURRO_01.mpg

And this is the Mediainfo of the resulting file:
https://gist.github.com/MoritzLost/491b7a79be3602e447a84971d4ae8057

Comment: Ok, ffmpeg muxes to MPEG-1 system by default for `.mpg` and AC-3 is not supported by most players in such a stream. Modified command.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that now. Does the force dvd parameter make it use MPEG-2 or what does it do?

Comment: Yes, an MPEG-2 PS.